# Can I self-distribute a Firefox web extension on an insecure server

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

I've written an addon and lets say it contains some sensitive information and I only want to share it with a group of people, while also maintaining the ability to distribute updates for it.

Before I can self-distribute it, it needs to be uploaded to addons.mozilla.org in order to be signed and it needs to point out to an a update manifest file, whenever a new version or update is available.

My update file looks like this:

```
{
  "addons": {
    "my_private_addon@example.com": {
      "updates": [
        { "version": "0.1",
          "update_link" : "http://example.com/addon_update_v_0.1.xpi",
          "update_hash" : "sha256:0FEE5D33C13546A599A54085DA6AC28FBF3D1678"
        },
        { "version": "0.2",
          "update_link" : "http://example.com/addon_update_v_0.2.xpi",
          "update_hash" : "sha256:C7C067E755B51A0D09BEB25B463CD25CCE26C92C"
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So far so good. But my main addon manifest file contains an update_url which leads to an insecure address, so therefor addon verification is rejected:

```
"applications": {
    "gecko": {
        "id": "my_private_addon@example.com",
        "update_url": "http://example.com/addon_update.json"
    }
}
```

Error on Mozilla addons page:

```
"/applications/gecko/update_url" should match format "secureUrl"

Error: Your JSON file could not be parsed.
```

I understand why this error is happening, but I am looking for a workaround. Is it only possible to self-distribute your addon only if you have a secure server at your disposal?

Answer (score 1):

There is the option to use an insecure `update_url` if you also provide `update_hash`.

> A cryptographic hash of the file pointed to by `update_link`. This must be provided if `update_link` is not a secure URL. If present, this must be a string beginning with either `sha256:` or `sha512:`, followed by the hexadecimal-encoded hash of the matching type.

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Updates

Answer (score 0):

> Is it only possible to self-distribute your addon only if you have a secure server at your disposal?

yes